# I can not connect to the mail with php script hostgator

Tags: php, imaplib

I've tried many ways but can not connect to imap in hostgator hosting, how do

Here is my code

```
   $mbox = imap_open("{mail.liveslink.com:143/notls/norsh/novalidate-cert}", "adriano@liveslink.com","clecio")or die(imap_last_error())or die("can't connect: ".imap_last_error());
```

I'm getting this error

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {mail.liveslink.com:143/notls/norsh/novalidate-cert} in /home3/adriano/public_html/teste/index.php on line 3
```

Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.

please help me

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below code, I tested and works like a charm!

```
<?php
    echo 'before imap_open';
    $inbox = imap_open("{mail.liveslink.com:143}","adriano@liveslink.com","clecio") or die('Could not connect to mail server');
    $num_msg = $imap_num_msg($inbox);
    echo $num_msg;
    imap_close($inbox);
?>
```